# Is there anyway to do "strikethrough" on a text file in Sublime?

Tags: text, sublimetext3, strikethrough

I like to make text files with Sublime and use them as daily-reminder lists. I would like to be able to strike a line through the things I've completed versus erase them. Is there any easy way to do this on Sublime?

Comment: For text content the only font effects Sublime supports are Bold and Italic. With a custom syntax you could perhaps assign a different visual color. You may want to check out [PlainTasks](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PlainTasks) though; it lets you visually check items that are complete or archive them by moving them to the bottom of the list.

Comment: @OdatNurd Hi. Bigfan here. Closely follow your youtube channel. Watched most of the YT channel videos on sublime customization. But I need this feature really badly. PlainTasks require you to create a separate file. What I want is to strikeout text with a shortcut in any file. Be is .txt or .cpp or .rb or .js file. I would love to talk to you (not through character llimiting comments) somewhere for explaining/building this as I am starting on your package development series. I just need a global shortcut to strikethrough text in any filetype. Really good work. Loved your latest sync video.

Answer (score 20):

I know I'm late to the game on this and this isn't exactly an answer to strikethrough but you can use the emojis in Sublime Text. For example I just use the green check mark emoji and put that in front of the line I'm marking as complete

✅

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @uriDium: my god bro, just copy the emoji and paste it in sublime and just reuse/repeat. There's no shortcuts for Emojis.

Comment: That's cute man. I appreciate it ✅

Comment: There is a partial shortcut, in Windows. `⊞`+`.` (winkey-period) will bring up a little menu full of emojis, and let you choose the one(s) you want. It works in most programs, including Sublime.

Comment: Nice one. 
Shortcut to avoid copy pasting emoji in sublime, 
Install emoji package, Run Package Control via CMD + Shift + P : select `Install Package` in the command palette and select `Emoji` from the list of packages.

CMD + Shift + P  : `Emoji: Insert Emoji` in the command palette and select the emoji to insert at the cursor(s).

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use an online Text Editor like [this](https://www.piliapp.com/cool-text/strikethrough-text/) and copy-paste into the Sublime Text.